# Injectivity of a rational function with a parameter: $x\bigl( \frac{1}{x^{2/3}}+x^\frac{1}{3}-h\bigr)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Assume that $h\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in{\mathbb{R^{+}}}$. For which values of the parameter $h$, do we have that $$f(x) = x\left( \frac{1}{x^{2/3}}+x^\frac{1}{3}-h\right)$$
is an injective function? When is it bijective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x\mapsto x^3$ is bijective on the nonnegative reals, you can study as well the function
$$
g(x)=x^3\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+x-h\right)=x^4-hx^3+x
$$
The derivative is
$$
g'(x)=4x^3-3hx^2+1
$$
and the problem translates into finding when this is never negative.

> The derivative is never negative if its minimum is nonnegative; the minimum is reached at one of the zeros of the second derivative $g''(x)=12x^2-6hx$, which are at $0$ and $h/2$. Now $g'(0)=1$ and $g'(h/2)=1-\frac{h^3}{4}$ which is nonnegative for $h^3\le 4$. If $h<0$ the value at $h/2$ doesn't need to be checked.

Comment: Also notice that $g'(x)$ has just two stationary points, in $x=0$ and $x=\frac{h}{2}$, hence if $g'(x)\geq 0$ for these two points, $g'(x)\geq 0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Again, thank you for the great answer, professor.

Comment: Professor, would you mind adding some remarks on how to graph (by hand -- that is, studying limits, derivatives, and so on) $x\bigl( \frac{1}{x^{2/3}}+x^\frac{1}{3}-h\bigr)$?

Comment: @mathlearner Use $f(x)=x^{1/3}+x^{4/3}-hx$. There's no real difficulty, in my opinion.

Comment: Prof @egreg, could I ask you to have a look at these questions http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170038/find-for-which-value-of-the-parameter-k-a-function-is-bijective  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170013/find-for-which-value-of-a-parameter-k-a-function-is-injective-surjective-or ? Thank you in advance.