# Find for which value of a parameter $k$ a function is injective, surjective, or bijective

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

Let 
$$f(x)=\ln(x^4-x^2+1)-2\ln(x^2+1)+2\sqrt3\arctan(\frac{2x^2-1}{\sqrt3}) + kx -k\ln x;$$
$$f_{*}(x)=\ln(x^4-x^2+1)-2\ln(x^2+1)+2\sqrt3\arctan(\frac{2x^2-1}{\sqrt3}) + kx;$$
$$f_{**}(x)=\ln(x^4-x^2+1)-2\ln(x^2+1)+2\sqrt3\arctan(\frac{2x^2-1}{\sqrt3});$$
for $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am a little stumped: how can I determine for what values of $k$, $f$ is (1) injective, (2) surjective; (3) bijective; and for what value of $k$, $f_{*}$ is $(1^*)$ injective, $(2^*)$ surjective; $(3^*)$ bijective? I have never done similar exercises before, and I'd be grateful if you could show me how to do it.

Also, can you show me how to draw the qualiative plot of $f(x)$, $f_{*}$ and $f_{**}$? I know I have to study the first and second derivative, and so on, but in practice, I found the task difficult for $f_{**}$ and I don't know how to proceed with the other two functions, which have parameters. Could you show me how to proceed?

Comment: Sorry, these look like *very* boring and useless exercises.

Comment: Prof. @egreg, I know, but I cannot solve them, and I would be *very* grateful if you could explain to me how to proceed.

Comment: Are you sure that the first term is $\ln(x^2-x^2+1)$? It probably is $\ln(x^2-x+1)$. Anyway, the drill is the same: for surjectivity find the limit at $-\infty$, the limit at $\infty$ (they must be distinct infinities); for injectivity, look at the derivative: the functions must be monotonic.

Comment: Prof. @egreg, yes, there was a typo (the correct writing was $\ln(x^4-x^2+1)$; thank you. I've edited the question. If you've got some time, could you show me how to solve the problem in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have easily
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f_{**}(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f_{**}(x)=\pi\sqrt{3}
$$
so
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}f_{*}(x)=
\begin{cases}
\infty & \text{if $k>0$,}\\
\pi\sqrt{3} & \text{if $k=0$,}\\
-\infty & \text{if $k<0$,}
\end{cases}
$$
while
$$
\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\begin{cases}
-\infty & \text{if $k>0$,}\\
-\pi\sqrt{3}/3 & \text{if $k=0$,}\\
\infty & \text{if $k<0$,}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f_{*}(x)=\begin{cases}
-\infty & \text{if $k>0$,}\\
\pi\sqrt{3} & \text{if $k=0$,}\\
\infty & \text{if $k<0$.}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus $f_{**}$ is neither injective nor surjective.

Thus surjectivity is ruled out for $f$ and $f_{*}$ when $k=0$. Also injectivity of $f_{*}$ is ruled out for $k=0$. On the other hand, $f$ and $f_{*}$ are surjective for $k\ne0$.

Now compute the derivatives and try deciding whether the functions $f$ and $f_{*}$ are monotonic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: May I ask you if you could have a look at this question too? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185916/how-to-prove-some-basic-propreties-of-orthogonal-complements