# Evaluating $ \frac{\sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{e^x-4}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How can I evaluate the following limit?
 $$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} \frac{\sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{e^x-4}$$

Update: 
Also, how can I evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0^{\pm}} \frac{\sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{e^x-4}$, $\lim_{x \to \ln2^{+}} \frac{\sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{e^x-4}$ and $\lim_{x \to \ln4^{+}} \frac{\sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{e^x-4}$. 
FInally, how can I draw by hand the qualitative graph of the function  $$\frac{\sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{e^x-4}$$ over the *reals*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You may just observe that
$$
|1-e^x| =
\begin{cases}
1-e^x,  & \text{if $x \to -\infty$} \\
e^x-1, & \text{if $x \to +\infty$.}
\end{cases}
$$ Then, as $x\to -\infty$, we have
$$
\frac{\sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{e^x-4}=\frac{\sqrt{(1-e^x)-1}}{e^x-4}=\frac{\sqrt{-e^x}}{e^x-4} =\frac{\pm i\sqrt{e^x}}{e^x-4} \longrightarrow 0
$$ As $x\to \infty$, we have
$$
\frac{\sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{e^x-4}=\frac{\sqrt{(e^x-1)-1}}{e^x-4}=\frac{\sqrt{e^x-2}}{e^x-4}\sim\frac{\sqrt{e^x}}{e^x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^x}}  \longrightarrow 0
$$

**Similarly**
$$"\frac{\sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{e^x-4}\sim \begin{cases}
\frac{\sqrt{|1-2|-1}}{2-4} = \frac{0}{-2}=0,  & \text{if $x \to (\ln 2)^-$} \\
\frac{\sqrt{|1-2|-1}}{2-4} = \frac{0}{-2}=0,  & \text{if $x \to (\ln 2)^+$}
\end{cases}"$$
$$"\frac{\sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{e^x-4}\sim \begin{cases}
\frac{\sqrt{|1-4|-1}}{0^-} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{0^-}=-\infty,  & \text{if $x \to (\ln 4)^-$} \\
\frac{\sqrt{|1-4|-1}}{0^+} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{0^+}=+\infty,  & \text{if $x \to (\ln 4)^+$}
\end{cases}"$$

Comment: I had forgotten to add some details. Could you check the updated question, please?

Comment: @mathlearner Observe that $\displaystyle \sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}$ is not defined as $x=0$ since the radicand is strictly negative we get $\sqrt{-1}$ ...

Comment: @mathlearner I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. With those limits and after computing the second derivative and studing the signs, I pretty much figured out how to draw the graph myself. However, the second derivative of the function seems very difficult to calculate. What would you do?

Comment: By the way, could you have a look at these two questions of mine: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170038/draw-the-plot-of-a-function-according-to-a-real-parameter-k-and-find-when-it-i  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170013/draw-the-qualitative-plot-of-a-function-and-find-for-which-value-of-a-parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

You should split the limit into two limits, since
$$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} e^x = \begin{cases}+\infty\\
0
\end{cases}$$

Therefore
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{e^x-4} = \frac{\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty } \sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} e^x-4} = \frac0{-4} = 0$$
because the two limits exist finite. The other case is an indeterminate form of the type $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, so some more work is needed:
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt{e^x - 1 - 1}}{e^x-4} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{e^{x/2}\sqrt{1 - 2e^{-x}}}{e^x(1 - 4e^{-x})} = 0$$

Now you can put the limits back together:
$$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} \frac{\sqrt{|1-e^x|-1}}{e^x-4} = 0$$

Comment: I had forgotten to add some details. Could you check the updated question, please?